# Solidworks API - Is view empty?

Tags: solidworks, solidworkspdmapi

Using Solidworks API, how can I find a drawing view is empty?

Same is the case with Sketch object.

I have searched the help file but can't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Most empty views are caused by Solidworks not being able to find the referenced document. You can check this with IView::ReferencedDocument. If it returns null, there's your problem. If it returns filepath, check if it exists.